# Using multi-output labels in keras ImageDataGenerator.flow() and using model.fit_generator()

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have a single-input,multi-output Neural Network model whose last layers are

```
out1 = Dense(168, activation = 'softmax')(dense)
out2 = Dense(11, activation = 'softmax')(dense)
out3 = Dense(7, activation = 'softmax')(dense)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[out1,out2,out3])
```

the Y-labels for each image are as follows

```
train
>>

              image_id    class_1   class_2  class_3    

0              Train_0         15         9        5    
1              Train_1        159         0        0
...
...
...
453651    Train_453651          0        15       34
453652    Train_453652         18         0        7
```

**EDIT:-**

```
train.iloc[:,1:4].nunique()
>>
class_1        168
class_2         11
class_3          7
dtype: int64
```

So looking at these different range of classes, should I use `categorical_crossentropy` or `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`? and how should I use the `Y_labels` in  flow for the code given below?

```
imgs_arr = df.iloc[:,1:].values.reshape(df.shape[0],137,236,1)
# 32332 columns representing pixels of 137*236 and single channel images.
# converting it to (samples,w,h,c) format

Y = train.iloc[:,1:].values #need help from here

image_data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(validation_split=0.25)
train_gen = image_data_gen.flow(x=imgs_arr, y=Y, batch_size=32,subset='training')
valid_gen = image_data_gen.flow(x=imgs_arr,y=Y,subset='validation')
```

is this this the right way to pass `Y`or use `Y=[y1,y2,y3]` where

```
y1=train.iloc[:,1].values
y2=train.iloc[:,2].values
y3=train.iloc[:,3].values
```

Comment: As any numpy array you would pass to a normal `fit` method.

Comment: You probably need a model with three outputs, each one with a `'softmax'` and a `'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'`, and you probably wouldn't need to change a thing on you y array. It just needs to be in the same order as the images.

Comment: @DanielMöller you mean a 3D, one-hot encoded array?

Comment: I mean three output tensors, all three tensors 2D, exactly as any other 2D for categorical classification models. If you use numeric labels, use three `'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'` losses. If you use one-hot labels, use three `'categorical_crossentropy'` losses.

Comment: Use `y = [y1, y2, y3]`

Comment: @DanielMöller number of classes differ in each of the class. For example, for the first one, there are 168 different classes and for the third, only 7. So what should I do in your opinion go for ```sparse``` or ```categorical```. and do I have to convert these using ```pd.get_dummies() ``` / ```np.to_categorical```(each_class,each_class_range) or just use the values as they re like a regression problem? please take a look at the edit .

Comment: Don't do anything, just go. "Sparse" takes numeric labels, just as they are now. The three outputs are separate, they will not relate to each other.

Comment: ```Y=[y1,y2,y3]``` throws an error **`x` (images tensor) and `y` (labels) should have the same length. Found: x.shape = (50210, 137, 236, 1), y.shape = (3, 50210)** @DanielMöller

Answer (score 3):

Ouch....

By the message given in your `flow`, you will need a single output. So you need to make the separation inside your model. (Keras failed to follow its own standards there)

This means something like:

```
Y = train.iloc[:,1:].values #shape = (50210, 3)
```

With a single output like:

```
out = Dense(168+11+7, activation='linear')(dense)
```

And a loss function that handles the separation:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    true1 = y_true[:,0:1]
    true2 = y_true[:,1:2]
    true3 = y_true[:,2:3]

    out1 = y_pred[:,0:168]
    out2 = y_pred[:,168:168+11]
    out3 = y_pred[:,168+11:]

    out1 = K.softmax(out1, axis=-1)
    out2 = K.softmax(out2, axis=-1)
    out3 = K.softmax(out3, axis=-1)

    loss1 = K.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(true1, out1, from_logits=False, axis=-1)
    loss2 = K.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(true2, out2, from_logits=False, axis=-1)
    loss3 = K.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(true3, out3, from_logits=False, axis=-1)

    return loss1+loss2+loss3
```

Compile the model with `loss=custom_loss`.

Then the `flow` should stop complaining when you do `flow`.

Just make sure X and Y are exactly in the same order: `imgs_arr[i]` corresponds to `Y[i]` correctly.

Comment: oh man!thanks a lot. My head was literally on the verge of exploding. I used the exact same thing what you just suggested me but without the custom loss. ```flow``` ran smoothly but the model was asking for 3 separate y_labels.

Comment: Curiosity: I'm training a model with outputs very similar to yours. 3 groups of categorical classes. I notice a certain group of classes may start overfitting sooner than the others, and that the losses are not completely balanced due to the different number of classes. But I still don't know what's the best way to balance the losses, and I asked this question: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/64205/balance-two-crossentropy-losses-with-different-number-of-neurons

Comment: Can you please tell me solution to one of my newest problems. There is no target_size in ```flow```. How can I resize my ```images_arr``` from ```(samples,137,236,1)``` to ```(samples,64,64,1)```?

Comment: You need to build your own generator.... see `Sequence` in https://keras.io/utils/

Comment: (I must go, sorry)

Comment: No idea man! That problem of yours is off my head. I'm just a college graduate wanted to be a professor but started working with Django, left it because it was kinda boring, but a newbie in ML  ( just 4 months) that's why I am having so much trouble. But I'll answer your question very soon. Had a glimpse of something like that in a book by MIT Press , I think

Comment: @DanielMöller, could you see [this link](https://gist.github.com/RyanAkilos/3808c17f79e77c4117de35aa68447045#gistcomment-3439342) where I am trying to get labels of validation set for `LABELS` in `metrics.roc_curve(LABELS, preds)`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is:

1. Make an array of tuple, then pass it to the ImageDataGenerator flow method.
2. Make an iterator method that accepts the iterator made by the previous step. This iterator converts back the array of tuple to list of arrays.

Here is the methods to implement the steps above:

```
def make_array_of_tuple(tuple_of_arrays):
    array_0 = tuple_of_arrays[0]
    array_of_tuple = np.empty(array_0.shape[0], dtype=np.object)
    for i, tuple_of_array_elements in enumerate(zip(*tuple_of_arrays)):
        array_of_tuple[i] = tuple_of_array_elements
    return array_of_tuple

def convert_to_list_of_arrays(array_of_tuple):
    array_length = array_of_tuple.shape[0]
    tuple_length = len(array_of_tuple[0])
    array_list = [
        np.empty(array_length, dtype=np.uint8) for i in range(tuple_length) ]
    for i, array_element_tuple in enumerate(array_of_tuple):
        for array, tuple_element in zip(array_list, array_element_tuple):
            array[i] = tuple_element
    return array_list

def tuple_of_arrays_flow(original_flow):
    while True:
        (X, array_of_tuple) = next(original_flow)
        list_of_arrays = convert_to_list_of_arrays(array_of_tuple)
        yield X, list_of_arrays
```

To call the ImageDataGenerator flow() method and get the flow used for the model:

```
y_train = make_array_of_tuple((y_train_1, y_train_2, y_train_3))
orig_image_flow = train_image_generator.flow(X_train, y=y_train)
train_image_flow = tuple_of_arrays_flow(orig_image_flow)
```

The size of y_train is the same as X_train, so it should be accepted.
'train_image_flow' returns list of arrays
that should be accepted by the Keras multi-output model.

**ADDED** (2019/01/26)

One another idea, simpler than the above one:

1. Pass array of indices, which contains 0, 1, 2, ..., to ImageDataGenerator.flow().
2. In the iterator, select the elements in the arrays for the multiple output by using the returned indices array from the original flow.

Here is the implementation:

```
def make_multi_output_flow(image_gen, X, y_list, batch_size):
    y_item_0 = y_list[0]
    y_indices = np.arange(y_item_0.shape[0])
    orig_flow = image_gen.flow(X, y=y_indices, batch_size=batch_size)

    while True:
        (X, y_next_i) = next(orig_flow)
        y_next = [ y_item[y_next_i] for y_item in y_list ]
        yield X, y_next
```

This is an example to call the method above.

```
y_train = [y_train_1, y_train_2, y_train_3]
multi_output_flow = make_multi_output_flow(
    image_data_generator, X_train, y_train, batch_size)
```